# How to get current row (element) on TreeEditor Button click event

Tags: swt, jface

```java
TreeViewerColumn colEdit= new TreeViewerColumn (viewer, column);
colEdit.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
   
    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {

        TreeItem item = (TreeItem) cell.getItem();
        Button btnEdit= new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),SWT.NONE);
        btnEdit.setText("Edit");

        TreeEditor editor = new TreeEditor(item.getParent());
        editor.grabHorizontal  = true;
        editor.grabVertical = true;
        editor.setEditor(btnEdit, item, cell.getColumnIndex());
        editor.layout();

        btnEdit.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // How to get current row element.
                TreeItem[] selection = treeViewer.getTree().getSelection(); // (Selection is empty, because click on button and selection not happened)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**`treeViewer.getTree().getSelection();`** return empty because Tree Editor with button control added and while button click row selection not happening.

**`cell.getElement()`** returning null in handler method.

btnEdit.setData can help me but Is there any way to get current row (element) on which button click event it clicked ??

Comment: If you are using TreeViewerColumn it is usually better to use EditingSupport (`ViewerColumn.setEditingSupport`). It deals with handling the selection and interfacing with the viewer content provider.

Comment: But here I always want to button visible so user can click, But for CellEdtior behavior is it get visible.when we click on cell.